# "(" unexpected error when setting regex pattern in a CLI argument using NPM scripts

Tags: node.js, regex, jestjs, package.json

The 2nd npm script below works as expected while the first throws the title error:

```
// package.json
"test": "jest --watch --testNamePattern=^(?!\\[functional\\]).+$",
"test:functional": "jest --watch --testNamePattern=[functional]",
```

```
// terminal
> jest --watch --testNamePattern=^(?!\[functional\]).+$

sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! projectName@1.0.0 test: `jest --watch --testNamePattern=^(?!\[functional\]).+$`
```

I guess I have a syntax error for that regex pattern? What is the correct syntax here?

**Also tried**

Forward slashes around the regex. This also failed, same error as above:

```
"test": "jest --watch --testNamePattern=/^(?!\\[functional\\]).+$/",
```

Comment: Perhaps try `--testNamePattern='^(?!\[functional\]).+$'`

Comment: Ok, this works. I see that the single quotes specified the argument more clearly for the CLI. Thank you